# Python - Beautifulsoup | Why does my find() not work?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am seriously losing my mind. Could someone please explain to me how this is resulting in "None" for me?

Thanks a lot for your support!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.amazon.de/LG-OLED55CX9LA-Fernseher-Triple-Modelljahr/dp/B084XSZW1M/ref=sr_1_3?__mk_de_DE=ÅMÅŽÕÑ&dchild=1&keywords=lg+cx+55&qid=1597706640&sr=8-3"
headersq = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1.2 Safari/605.1.15"}

page = requests.get(url,headers=headersq)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")

price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice")

print(price)
```

Comment: Can you include the HTML source here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `lxml` as a parser instead of `html.parser`. install it using `pip install lxml`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.amazon.de/LG-OLED55CX9LA-Fernseher-Triple-Modelljahr/dp/B084XSZW1M/ref=sr_1_3?__mk_de_DE=ÅMÅŽÕÑ&dchild=1&keywords=lg+cx+55&qid=1597706640&sr=8-3"
headersq = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1.2 Safari/605.1.15"}

page = requests.get(url,headers=headersq)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"lxml")

price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice")

print(price.text)
```

Outputs:

```
1.965,63 €
```